# Why is try {} on my ps1 script wont work?

Tags: powershell

I have a code like this:

```
$powerSchemes = powercfg /l | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_ -match 'Power Scheme GUID:\s*([-0-9a-f]+)\s*\(([^)]+)\)\s*(\*)?') { 
        [PsCustomObject]@{ 
            GUID       = $matches[1] 
            SchemeName = $matches[2] -eq 'Ultimate Performance' 
            Active     = $matches[3] 
        } 
    } 
} 
 
$customScheme = $powerSchemes | Where-Object { $_.SchemeName -eq 'Ultimate Performance' } 
 
try { 
    if (!$customScheme.Active) {
        powercfg /s $($customScheme.GUID) 
    }
} catch { 
    powercfg -duplicatescheme e9a42b02-d5df-448d-aa00-03f14749eb61 
    if (!$customScheme.Active) {
        powercfg /s $($customScheme.GUID) 
    }
}
```

I make a `try{}` cause I know not everyone going to have Ultimate Performance powerplan. But it give me error

```
powercfg : Invalid Parameters -- try "/?" for help
At C:\Users\MyWin\Desktop\PowerPlan.ps1:15 char:3
+         powercfg /s $($customScheme.GUID)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Invalid Parameters -- try "/?" for help:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

isn't `try{}` going ignore

```
try { 
    if (!$customScheme.Active) {
        powercfg /s $($customScheme.GUID) 
    }
```

and just jump to the `catch{}`??

Sorry I'm a newbie though, if you need more information about the code, just tell me

reason I didnt put

```
powercfg -duplicatescheme e9a42b02-d5df-448d-aa00-03f14749eb61 
if (!$customScheme.Active) {
   powercfg /s $($customScheme.GUID)
```

on `try{}` so it didn't keep making new powerplan, if theres already **Ultimate Performance** powerplan, then just active it

Comment: It seems `powercfg /s $($customScheme.GUID) ` is what is throwing the error

Comment: Try {} will only catch Terminating Errors. Place $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" before the Try and clear it after the Catch{}.

Comment: it is the ```powercfg /s $($customScheme.GUID)```, because theres no Ultimate performance yet. Thats why I use ```try{}```. So it can make a new one if it doesn't have it and won't make it if its already have it. So it didn't fill the powerplan option

Answer (score 1):

*** UPDATED ***
Actually you don't even need a try/catch block:

```
Clear-Host

$TestScheme = 'Ultimate Performance'

$powerSchemes = powercfg /l | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_ -match 'Power Scheme GUID:\s*([-0-9a-f]+)\s*\(([^)]+)\)\s*(\*)?') { 
        [PsCustomObject]@{ 
            GUID       = $matches[1] 
            SchemeName = $matches[2]  
            Active     = $matches[3] -eq '*'
        } 
    } 
} 
 
$powerschemes   #*** For Debugging Only ***
 
$customScheme = $powerSchemes | Where-Object { $_.SchemeName -eq "$TestScheme" } 

$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"        #*** For Debugging Only ***
"`nCustom Scheme: $($customScheme.SchemeName) `n"  #*** For Debugging Only ***
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"                #*** For Debugging Only ***

If ($Null -eq $CustomScheme) {
  "Power scheme named: $TestScheme does NOT Exist!"
}

Else {

      If ($customScheme.Active) {
        "$TestScheme scheme ACTIVE!" 
      } 
      Else { 
       "$TestScheme Not Active" 
      }

} #End Else
```

Test this code on my Dell XPS8920 which has an Ultimate Performance scheme.

I've completely rewritten the code and I think it covers the bases. Note: that I changed your Custom PSObject logic to keep the name and indicate the status in the Active property.

Here are the test results with debugging information included, you can delete the code marked as such for production.

```
GUID                                 SchemeName               Active
----                                 ----------               ------
381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e Balanced                  False
49ef8fc0-bb7f-488e-b6a0-f1fc77ec649b Dell                      False
831878fb-3408-4f4b-a88c-72fdbe2ced67 Ultimate Performance       True
8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c High performance          False
a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a Power saver               False
a7573aee-d201-4451-bf29-7165c6858f5c winword                   False
f92ea615-6000-45ae-96b2-cb6c364f0ae4 MRBackup                  False
fce6c371-318d-4bc2-b28e-6425737e2eef Samsung High Performance  False

Custom Scheme: Ultimate Performance 

Ultimate Performance scheme ACTIVE!


GUID                                 SchemeName               Active
----                                 ----------               ------
381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e Balanced                  False
49ef8fc0-bb7f-488e-b6a0-f1fc77ec649b Dell                      False
831878fb-3408-4f4b-a88c-72fdbe2ced67 Ultimate Performance       True
8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c High performance          False
a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a Power saver               False
a7573aee-d201-4451-bf29-7165c6858f5c winword                   False
f92ea615-6000-45ae-96b2-cb6c364f0ae4 MRBackup                  False
fce6c371-318d-4bc2-b28e-6425737e2eef Samsung High Performance  False

Custom Scheme: Ultimate Performance 

Ultimate Performance scheme ACTIVE!

GUID                                 SchemeName               Active
----                                 ----------               ------
381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e Balanced                  False
49ef8fc0-bb7f-488e-b6a0-f1fc77ec649b Dell                      False
831878fb-3408-4f4b-a88c-72fdbe2ced67 Ultimate Performance      False
8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c High performance           True
a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a Power saver               False
a7573aee-d201-4451-bf29-7165c6858f5c winword                   False
f92ea615-6000-45ae-96b2-cb6c364f0ae4 MRBackup                  False
fce6c371-318d-4bc2-b28e-6425737e2eef Samsung High Performance  False

Custom Scheme:  

Power scheme named: Test does NOT Exist!
```

Comment: But if the computer doesn't have Ultimate Performance, it will not make it and just giving error. Thats why I have ```powercfg -duplicatescheme e9a42b02-d5df-448d-aa00-03f14749eb61``` code

Answer (score 0):

Since the SchemeNames returned by `powercfg` are LOCALIZED, you should not compare against that, but always use the GUID.

In your case, you want to activate the Ultimate Performance scheme, which is not enabled by default and therefore chances are `powercfg /l` does not show this scheme.

Try

```
$desiredScheme = 'e9a42b02-d5df-448d-aa00-03f14749eb61'  # we want to activate Ultimate Performance
$powerSchemes  = powercfg /l | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_ -match 'Power Scheme GUID:\s*([-0-9a-f]+)\s*\(([^)]+)\)\s*(\*)?') { 
        [PsCustomObject]@{ 
            GUID       = $matches[1] 
            SchemeName = $matches[2]
            Active     = $matches[3] -eq '*'  # --> $true or $false
        } 
    } 
} 

# GUID                                 SchemeName          Active
# ----                                 ----------          ------
# 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e Balanced             False
# 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c High performance      True
# a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a Power saver          False
# e9a42b02-d5df-448d-aa00-03f14749eb61 Ultimate Performance False

# NOTE
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 1) The Ultimate Performance scheme may not appear here because it is not enabled by default
# 2) The SchemeName is LOCALIZED, like in Dutch NL pc 'Power saver' is 'Energiebesparing' etc.
#    This means you should not compare on the SchemeName, but use the GUID instead


$currentScheme = $powerSchemes | Where-Object { $_.GUID -eq $desiredScheme }
if (!$currentScheme) {
    # scheme 'Ultimate Performance' not found, so enable it first
    powercfg /duplicatescheme $desiredScheme
    # and set it active
    powercfg /s $desiredScheme
}
elseif (!$currentScheme.Active) {
    powercfg /s $desiredScheme  # or use: $currentScheme.GUID
}
```

If after this you want to check if the power scheme has been set to Ultimate Performance, do

```
# test if the setting is as desired (just compare GUIDs)
$currentScheme = (powercfg.exe /GETACTIVESCHEME) -replace '.*GUID:\s*([-a-f0-9]+).*', '$1'
if ($currentScheme -eq $desiredScheme) {
    Write-Host "Current Power plan Settings: $($desiredScheme.SchemeName).!"
}
else {
    # exit the script here???
    Throw "Power plan Settings did not change to $($desiredScheme.SchemeName).!"
}
```